# Image panorama stitching black spots

Tags: opencv

Maybe someone knows what can cause that problem.
I have a simple code for stitching 12 images in one panorama image, but faced with strange behaviour.
Here the result of stitching on my MacBook Pro:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f_7i_rb8pnbHEBxlowzFa13MAHvxN07u

And result of stitching on my Desktop Mac:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=19CoyPzz6QgDjqG1lUZbphGPYvCAg41hi

The code i used is the **same** and images same too. On my desktop mac i can build and run it without problems, but on my MacBook it not working at all, it shows me the next error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (imgs.size() == imgs_.size())
in composePanorama, file /tmp/opencv-20171031-87373-6u1izq/opencv-3.3.1/modules/stitching/src/stitcher.cpp, line 168

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /tmp/opencv-20171031-87373-6u1izq/opencv-3.3.1/modules/stitching/src/stitcher.cpp:168:
error: (-215) imgs.size() == imgs_.size() in function composePanorama
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/stitching.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv ) {

    vector<Mat> images_arr;

    const string images[] = {
        "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/test_stitch/1.jpeg",
        "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/test_stitch/2.jpeg",
        "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/test_stitch/3.jpeg",
        "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/test_stitch/4.jpeg",
        "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/test_stitch/5.jpeg",
        "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/test_stitch/6.jpeg",
        "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/test_stitch/7.jpeg",
        "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/test_stitch/8.jpeg",
        "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/test_stitch/9.jpeg",
        "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/test_stitch/10.jpeg",
        "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/test_stitch/11.jpeg",
        "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/test_stitch/12.jpeg",
    };


    const char* outFile =  "/Users/george/CLionProjects/OpenCV_Stitch/out.jpeg";

    for(auto path : images) {
        Mat image = imread(path, IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_2 | IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION);
        images_arr.push_back(image);
    }

    Mat pano;
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(false);
    stitcher.setRegistrationResol(0.8);
    stitcher.setSeamEstimationResol(0.1);
    stitcher.setCompositingResol(1);
    stitcher.setPanoConfidenceThresh(1);
    stitcher.setWaveCorrection(true);
    stitcher.setWaveCorrectKind(detail::WAVE_CORRECT_HORIZ);
    Stitcher::Status status1 = stitcher.estimateTransform(images_arr);
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.composePanorama(images_arr, pano);

    if (status != Stitcher::OK) {
        cout << "Can't stitch images, error code = " << int(status) << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    imwrite(outFile, pano);

    return 0;
}
```

My CmakeLists.txt configuration:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(OpenCV_Stitch)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(OpenCV_Stitch ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(OpenCV_Stitch ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Can't even imagine what can cause that black spots on image. Did anyone come across this? And sometimes, when i use different images to stitch opencv returns error: **Camera parameters adjusting failed**
How can i prevent that? Maybe use some methods to estimate camera rotation or something like that?

Here the link to images what i try to stitch:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-DfSf8eaC7bi37-ZhBpaRt8jHVvO_Qwb

Thanks!

Comment: do you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: Nope, black spots stay on image.

Comment: What are you using for open/see the pic? I m wondering if it could be a sort of bad random behavior of the OS. Are you opening the pic inside eclipse using the “preview” app?

Comment: Yes, I'm open it with Preview.app. The same that i used on my desktop mac. I'm used many tools to open that image, same result. It's not related to app that i used for preview, image itself generated like that with artifacts.

Comment: Could you try a slightly change? add the following lines:
namedWindow("pano", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("pano", pano);
and see if the image actually has these black blobs?

Comment: Nope, result the same. I think a problem somehow related to parameters:
**setRegistrationResol(0.8);**
**setSeamEstimationResol(0.1);**
because when i change them the amount of black blobs changes too. Or maybe something wrong with **homogeneous coordinates** estimation? But not sure why that happens only on my laptop.

Comment: I know a few years later, but I'm still seeing the same issue. Were you able to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i get the same error message with your code. when i modified the part below it runs without error.

```
Mat pano;
Ptr<Stitcher> stitcher = Stitcher::create(Stitcher::PANORAMA, false);
stitcher->setRegistrationResol(0.8);
stitcher->setSeamEstimationResol(0.1);
stitcher->setCompositingResol(1);
stitcher->setPanoConfidenceThresh(1);
stitcher->setWaveCorrection(true);
stitcher->setWaveCorrectKind(detail::WAVE_CORRECT_HORIZ);
Stitcher::Status status = stitcher->stitch(images_arr, pano);
```

Comment: Hi, could you confirm if the generated image was complete? I tried here with 3.0 but the result is just the left side of the target image.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that code compile but result image stays the same ( with black spots ).

Comment: what is your OpenCV version? i use OpenCV 3.3.1 and the result is good.